# Windows Genuine Check out of date

Tags: windows-7, installation, updates

I'm trying to download the WM feature pack for my Windows 7 K install [from this page](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=16546).

However the version of `GenuineCheck.exe` that arrives doesn't run (an error message says its out of date). I've tried launching via a range of browsers but no joy.

Is there somewhere I can d/load a current version of this application or is there something wrong with my machine/set-up?

Comment: Does your Windows 7 installation have Service Pack 1 installed?

Comment: Try downloading it on a different PC using Internet Explorer, save the Media Feature Pack to a flash drive.

Comment: I'll give it a go, thanks. Care to share the reasoning behind your suggestion? Or is this one of those mysterious tricks (like re-booting) of the Wintel realm?